# Unix script to recursively search a directory and sub directories to grep and print content between 2 patterns in file

Tags: unix, scripting

I have some files in a directory and sub directories. I need to search all the files and print the  file name and the content between 2 matching patterns in the file.

For e.g. lets say my file looks like below.

```
File1.txt:
Pattern1
ABCDEFGHI
Pattern2
dafoaf
fafaf
dfadf
afadf

File2.txt
Pattern1
XXXXXXXXX
Pattern2
kdfaf
adfdaf
fdafad
```

I need to get following output

```
File1.txt:
ABCDEGHI
File2.txt:
XXXXXXXX
```

and so on for all the files under directory and sub directories separated by new line.

Comment: `I have never written any shell script before.` -- Unless you **attempt**, you'll **never** be able to write one.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
find . \
     -type f \
     -exec awk 'BEGING {print FILENAME ":"} /Pattern1/ { p=1 ; next } /Pattern2/ {p=0} p==1 {print $0} END {print ""}' \{\} \;
```

Note, this prints the `FILENAME`, even if `Pattern1` was not found!

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you :

Create this shell script as my_grep.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

grep -nH "Pattern" $1 >>temp

if [ `grep -c $1 temp` -eq 2 ]; then
        limits=`grep $1 temp | cut -f2 -d:`
        lower_limit=`echo $limits | cut -f1 -d" "`
        upper_limit=`echo $limits | cut -f2 -d" "`

        echo "$1:"
        head -`expr $upper_limit - 1` $1 | tail -`expr $upper_limit - $lower_limit - 1`
fi
```

Use find command to search files and fire this schell script:

```
$ find ./test -type f -exec ./my_grep {} \;
./test/File1.txt:
ABCDEFGHI
./test/File2.txt:
XXXXXXXXX
```